# Discord snap package spams journal

Tags: snap, apparmor

Journalctl shows that the Discord snap package / apparmor prints many messages to the systemd journal. Is there a way to fix this problem? The problem seems to have been happening for some time. I've seen it on 19.04 and 19.10.

The messages are very frequent. My machine has been up for less than an hour and I see many messages:

```
$ journalctl -b | grep discord | wc -l
20235
```

An example error message:

```
audit[4597]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4597 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
```

Here is an error message from another machine. Although the vast majority of the messages are related to ptrace (see above), some look like this (pid=6711 is ssh-agent).

```
audit[7358]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/6711/cmdline" pid=7358 comm="Discord" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, i fixed it by running

```
snap connect discord:system-observe :system-observe 
snap connect discord:unity7 :unity7
```

as seen [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/discord-ptrace-apparmor-denials/5099).

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the error messages but gives Discord the ability to read information from the other processes on the system (presumably to support which games are running so that status messages can be updated). The link Yoh129 provides gives more information. Just mentioning it since this fix might not be what everyone wants.

Comment: On the Github for the Discord Snap package is [a long discussion](https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/23) weather this should be allowed or not. I would argue that it should not be allowed and this answer enables spyware on your system. It is spyware, because this service is still enabled and reports back to discord even if you disable all settings regarding this feature.